# Failure/Error: config.include ::Rails::Controller::Testing::TemplateAssertions, type: :controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to run a single test file: `bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb`

But get following error:

```
    An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/user_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: config.include ::Rails::Controller::Testing::TemplateAssertions, type: :controller

NameError:
  uninitialized constant Rails::Controller
  Did you mean?  ApiController
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:149:in `block in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:61:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:3:in `require'
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
```

Initially, I was getting following error:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/user_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: module Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel

NameError:
  uninitialized constant Shoulda
# ./spec/support/matchers/validate_kept_of_matcher.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:51:in `block in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:51:in `each'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:51:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:3:in `require'
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
```

But then it fixed after I added following to the test file.

`require "shoulda/matchers"`

I am newbie in Ruby/Rails world, can someone please give a direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rails::Controller::Testing::TemplateAssertions` [was removed in Rails 5](https://bigbinary.com/blog/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5).

You can re-add the depreciated functionality by installing the [Rails controller testing gem](https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing). However the use of controller specs, assigns and template assertions is discouraged by both the RSpec and Rails teams and is not very future proof.

The community accepted solution is to write [request specs](https://everydayrails.com/2016/08/29/replace-rspec-controller-tests.html) and stop poking inside your controllers.